# Web.config URL redirect to non-www + https

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

Currently, my rule is:

```
<rule name="SecureRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The problem is here:

`http://www.domainName.com/image.png`  redirects wrongly to `https://domainName.com`
instead of `https://domainName.com/image.png`

and

`https://www.domainName.com/image.png` doesn't ever redirect to `https://domainName.com/image.png`

So, what's the true way to redirect all to non-www https URL?

Answer (score 1):

The correct rule, which will fit all your requirements is:

```
<rule name="SecureRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: It returns error 500 on IIS10, any way to make it work on IIS10?

Comment: It should work with IIS 10 as well. It might return 500 if you pasted this rule into the wrong place in web.config or if URL rewrite module not installed

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it on my site is as follows:

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by this in the web-config environment!

Comment: This answer is not for IIS

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
<rule name="SecureRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```